# Change text within a span with a rotation effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the text within a span with a specific effect when a boostrap carousel slides to a new item. The concerned text being the id of the new image displayed in the carousel.

The following code works alright :

```
$('.carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        $('#landing-displayed-item').fadeOut();
    setTimeout( function(){
        $('#landing-displayed-item').text($('.carousel').find('.active').find('img').attr('id'));
        $('#landing-displayed-item').fadeIn();
    }, 750);
});
```

But I'd like the animation not to be a fadeOut/fadeIn, but a rotation effect similar to [the one seen here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/jquery-super-simple-text-rotator/index3.html).

Hence I tried the following code, but it doesn't work (the text changes with no animation at all) :

```
$('.carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    setTimeout( function(){
        $('#landing-displayed-item').text($('.carousel').find('.active').find('img').attr('id')).show().css({
          "-webkit-transform": " rotate(0) scale(1)",
          "-moz-transform": "rotate(0) scale(1)",
          "-o-transform": "rotate(0) scale(1)",
          "transform": "rotate(0) scale(1)"
        });
    }, 750);
});
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo:

```js
var count=0;

$('a').click(function() {
  $('div').addClass('rotate')
          .delay(500)
          .queue(function(n) {
            $(this).html("Another Text"+count).removeClass('rotate');
            n();
          })
  count++;
});
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition:all .5s linear;
  transform-origin: center;
}
div.rotate {
  transform:rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"> Change Text</a>
<div>This is text for Slide</div>
```